# Move object along local axis with Python API

Tags: python, objects, transforms

How to move object along it's local axis without using operators?

In my case I have objects scattered along curve with Follow Path constraint:
 [example blendfile](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47025).
*Which, I guess, is irrelevant when using `matrix_world` for applying transformations.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out having constraints on object is relevant – cannot use `matrix_world` for applying transforms. Instead use `matrix_basis`, to get access to location, rotation and scale, before constraints and parenting are applied.

Following code will move object along its Z axis:

```
from mathutils import Matrix

loc = Matrix.Translation((0.0, 0.0, 1.5))
ob.matrix_basis @= loc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `location` property, which already is in local coordinates.

Comment: Object's location property displaying local coordinates relative to object's parent, world or constraint, not the object's local coordinates.

Comment: "coordinates relative to object's parent" -- that is what "local coordinates" are. The `location` property is just that.

Comment: Download example file, select object on curve and change it's Z location, you'll see that it's not moving along object's local Z axis. To move object along it's local axis, you have to switch Manipulator's Transform Orientation to Local.

Comment: I'm sorry, in my first comment I mistakenly used the term "object's local coordinates". What I meant is that object's location property doesn't take into account object's orientation (or local axis).